# MacOS - Admin account requires password for every action

Tags: macos, osx-lion, user-accounts

I am running MacOS Lion and have a user account that has Admin privileges (not the System Administrator [root] account). My problem is for every action I make the "enter password" popup appears. This wasn't much of an issue before I installed XAMPP.

XAMPP requires to be setup in /Applications. The problem now is when using TextMate or Transmit I can't create / add files. At moments TextMate pops up the "enter password" box, however Transmit doesn't and can't write to the folder.

Changing write permissions on the /htdocs/ folder seems to help for a while and then it starts displaying the password box - again.

Should I continue using this account or should I switch everything to the System Administrator account?